# "Represent" vs "stand for" vs "means"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, synonyms, academia

I am writing an academic paper.
I wrote the following sentences

> Notation *A ↔ B* **stands for** that *A* corresponds to *B*. *Qualid* and *ident*
> **stand for** qualified identifiers  and simple identifiers,
> respectively.

In the above example, I used "stand for" twice. My friend suggested me to replace the first
"stand for" with "represent".
Thus, I should use "Notation *A ↔ B* represents that *A* corresponds to *B*".
However, he told me that using "stand for" for "*Qualid* and *ident*" made no problem.

I cannot understand the reason why "Notation *A ↔ B* stands for that *A*" is unsuitable.
Moreover, I am confused with the reason why "*Qualid* and *ident* stand for" is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the first *stands for* should be replaced with **means**. Neither *stands for* ***that*** nor *represents* ***that*** works in this context. Also, you need the definite article (*the*) at the start of the sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for your help! I came to realize the difference between "mean" and "represent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation in this scenario would be to use "specifies".

> Notation A ↔ B **specifies** that A corresponds to B.

You are stating how the notation works and outlining the specifications for your notation format. I see this word used a lot in technical writing and I think it works well here.